# Как подставить в колонну в таблице tableWidget блок dataEdit? В Qt designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qtablewidget

Как подставить блок `dataEdit` в определенный столбец в таблицу `TableWidget`.

Если можно, то как провернуть данные действия в *Qt designer*?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте ваш модуль `.ui` и лучше  расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: В вопросе про таймер и расчёт времени, вы использовали таблицу в первом столбце которой распологаются dataEdit. Вопрос как dataEdit поместить в таблицу в qt designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сможете сделать это с помощью *Qt Designer*,
сейчас можно вставить только текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое простое и практичное решение - сделать это с помощью кода,
примерно так:

```
    ...
    row = 3
    column = 2
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(row, column)
    
    for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        date_from.setDateTime(

# так            
#            QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 9, 4))
# или так
            QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26), QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
        )

        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)    # !!!    
    ...
```

> void **QTableWidget**::**setCellWidget**(int **row**, int **column**, QWidget ***widget**)
>
> Устанавливает данный виджет для отображения в ячейке в данной строке и столбце,
> передавая владение виджетом таблице.

Comment: При попытке вставить данный отрезок кода PyCharm указывает на ошибку. Скрин  выше.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров это уже другой вопрос - задайте новый вопрос, приведите ваш код, не картинкой, а обычным текстом. Примите решение по вопросу: 'Как подставить в колонну в таблице tableWidget блок dataEdit? В Qt designer'.

Comment: данный код вставлять в ui или в логику программы?

Comment: @АндрейАлександров  в логику программы

Comment: я вставил в тестовый файл и dataEdit не вставляется

Comment: @АндрейАлександров задавайте новый вопрос. Прикрепляйте код, который демонстрирует что вы  делаете и опишите что вы хотите сделать.